# css dropdown menu typesetting

Tags: html, css, django

Please help me with this dropdown menu typesetting .

this is my typesetting now:

[image]

And I want the word(Engliash and Traditional Chinese(Taiwan) more closely like this

[image]

I try for a while,still can't try out 
Please guide me thank you very much.

here is my code:
The `#dropdownmenu` is a `div` under a div which id =header

jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/kkadso/yk3tprnv/1/

```
<ul id="header">
    <li data-menuanchor="firstPage"><a href="#">About</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div id='dropmenu'>
            <img src="{% static 'img/lan.png' %}" />
            <ul class="submenu">

                <input name="language" type="hidden" id="lang"/>
                <li  value="en" id="langtext"><a href="#" >English</a></li>
                <li  value="zh-tw" id="langtext"><a href="#" >Traditional Chinese(Taiwan)</a></li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Put your codes in JSFiddle.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kkadso/yk3tprnv/1/  here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make following changes changes in css:

```
#dropmenu {
    position : relative;
}

#dropmenu > ul {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #000;
    display: none;    //<- this should be uncommented
    /*width: 100px;*/ //<-this should be commented
}
#dropmenu:hover > ul {
    display: block!important; // !mportant must be added to show child content when hover
    background: #666666;
    padding-left: 0;          //<- This must be added
}
#dropmenu:hover > ul > li {
    position : relative;      //<-This must be relative
}
#langtext > a {
    font-size: 0.8rem;
}

#header {
    text-align: center;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 60px;
    z-index: 70;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    /* postition: relative; */ //<-This must be commented
}
#header li {
    font-size: 1rem;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 20px;
    color: #e6e7e8;
    text-align: left;    // <- This must be added. Aligning text.
}
#header li.active {
    color: #fff;
}
#header li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #e6e7e8;
}
#header li.active a:hover {
    color: #fff;
}
#header li:hover {
    background-color: transparent;
}
#header li a,
#header li.active a {
    display: block;
    white-space: pre;
}
#header li.active a {
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 600;
}
```

Here is [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/yk3tprnv/11/).
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! Can the Engliash and Traditional Chinese(Taiwan) distance(there is space between them) more closely? ,sorry my english expression not good enough.

Comment: Yes it is possible do you need them also?

Comment: So you can manipulate margin of #header ul.submenu>li { margin:10px; }

Comment: It's not ok . I think it's because this : #header li { margin: 20px; } anyway thank you for helping me so a lot!!

Comment: @user2492364 Can you state clearly what size of margin you need to li? I mean margin-right, margin-top, margin-left, margin-bottom. Should it be different for first and last li?

Comment: no,first and last li would be the same. margin :10 px is ok